# android flyin imageView after a certain time

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview, postdelayed

The purpose I aming for is, that 2 seconds after my activity was started an ImageView (with an image) should flyIn to the view. But with the following code nothing happens.

Am I on the right way or can I solve this completely different?
What do I have to change that this works?

Here is how my code looks:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private ImageView _truck;
    private Handler _flyInTruckHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        _truck = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_garbageTruck);
        _truck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        _flyInTruckHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                _truck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };

        _flyInTruckHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new flyInTruck();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    class flyInTruck extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(                      getApplicationContext(), R.anim.flyin);
        findViewById(R.id.main_garbageTruck).setAnimation(anim);
            _flyInTruckHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            anim.start();
        }
    }
}
```

The animation I use is from here : [Fly In Animation for a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991279/fly-in-animation-for-a-gridview)
But slightly changed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="true" >
    <scale
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Ok, I got it (so simple and I didn't thought about that before).
I do not need that extra class "flyInTruck". I just can write it like this:

```
    _flyInTruckHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.flyin);
            findViewById(R.id.main_garbageTruck).setAnimation(anim);
            _flyInTruckHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            anim.start();
        }
    }, 2000);
```